# Problema con mostrar algo en media query

Tags: html, css, scss

estoy utilizando display none para ocultar cosas que implemento en el codigo y luego mostrarlos cuando se cumple un maximo menor a 990px, no se si me explique del todo bien, pero el problema es que al poner "Display: none" en el codigo, este desaparece, luego voy a @media (max-width:910px) a colocar display:block, pero no aparece. Adjunto codigo:

```
 & button{
       display: none;
    }


@media (max-width:980px){

header{
    & nav{

        
        & ul{
            nav ul button{
                display:block;
                background-image: url("../img/menu.png");
                height: 42px;
                width: 42px;
                background-size: 42px;
                background-color: transparent;
                outline:none;
                border: none;
                position: absolute;
                left: 15px;
        }
```

Estoy citando bien a el boton en el codigo css, hice otras pruebas antes por ejemplo sin el display block y los cambios en el media query me los tomaba bien, tambien use otro archivo vacio sin tanto codigo para probar y me funciona el metodo de "display: none" y "display:block" entonces no se cual es el problema de este codigo. Adjunto tambien el codigo HTML:

```
      <nav>
          
            <ul>

              <li><a class="current" href="">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Descargas</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Capacitacion</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Noticias</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
              <button id="btn" alt=""></button>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

Aprecio mucho su ayuda. Gracias!

Comment: Podría ser un problema de [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), donde la primera regla es más específica que la usada en _media query_. Por favor edita la pregunta para poner el código de la regla inicial y poder realizar pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

display no funciona muy bien con querys.
Prueba con opacity: 0; para ocultar y con valor 1 para mostrar.
O bien, intentalo con visibility: hidden; para no mostrarlo o visibility: visible; para mostrarlo.
Un saludo.